# App quits with unhandled exception when <RelativeLayout> contains <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout />

Tags: android-studio

My app is crashing whenever I have a drawer layout within a RelativeLayout. I scoured the net looking for something similar but haven't seen anything. The project renders correctly in the preview but when it comes to running on the emulator, it crashes. Here's my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bnrLogoYellow"
        android:layout_width="195dp"
        android:layout_height="69dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/bnrlogo_yellow" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imgbtnGrub"
        android:layout_width="95dp"
        android:layout_height="95dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/burgersquare"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bnrLogoYellow"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imgbtnPub"
        android:layout_width="95dp"
        android:layout_height="95dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/pubsquare1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bnrLogoYellow"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgbtnGrub"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imgbtnKooz"
        android:layout_width="95dp"
        android:layout_height="95dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/koozsquare"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bnrLogoYellow"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgbtnPub"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imgbtnMore"
        android:layout_width="95dp"
        android:layout_height="95dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/moresquare"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bnrLogoYellow"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgbtnKooz"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/DemoImage"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@null"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imgbtnGrub"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom = "true"
        android:src="@drawable/slidemenu1" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imgbtnGrub"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom = "true">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/navList"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="left|start"
            android:alpha="0.75"
            android:background="#ffee33"
            android:divider="@null"
            android:theme="?attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I can reproduce the exception without even having written any Java code. The exception I get says:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class
>   loader; no stack trace available
>
> android.widget.ViewStub

Any help with this is greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is probably a dumb question, but have you tried a different layout?

Comment: I wish I could use an alternate layout scheme, but I really need to use a RelativeLayout for what I'm doing. On a side note, I created a test project and wrapped the DrawerLayout inside of a LinearLayout and that didn't crash when I ran it - so it's definitely something with the RelativeLayout that DrawerLayout doesn't like.

Answer (score 1):

While not a real solution, I did find a workaround. I wrapped the DrawerLayout inside a LinearLayout which is inside the RelativeLayout. Here's how my XML ended up looking:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_below="@id/imgbtnGrub"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imgbtnGrub"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom = "true">


        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/navList"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="left|start"
            android:alpha="0.75"
            android:background="#ffee33"
            android:divider="@null"
            android:theme="?attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Hopefully it helps someone else out there that might run into the same problem.